# Pandas get_dummies generates multiple columns for the same feature

Tags: python, pandas, one-hot-encoding

I'm using a pandas series and trying to convert it to one hot encoding. I'm using the `describe` method in order to check how many unique categories the series has. The output is:

```
input['pattern'].describe(include='all')

    count     9725
    unique       7
    top          1
    freq      4580
    Name: pattern, dtype: object
```

When I'm trying:

```
    x = pd.get_dummies(input['pattern'])
    x.describe(include= 'all')
```

I get 18 classes with 12 classes which are completely zeros. How come did `get_dummies` produced classes which did not occur even once in the input?

Comment: I have no clue what your problem is, as I cannot see your data. Can you do something about that?

Comment: My data is just numbers in an object format like: ['0','0','5','6',....]. It originally had 18 classes but all the high classes were changed to class '6' and the describe method confirms that. All the high generated classes are all zeros.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand, and your explanation doesn't help much. All get dummies does is convert your column to a dataframe of encodings. Count the number of columns - that's the number of unique features you have. Calling `describe` on the output makes little to no sense, since it's just 0s and 1s.

Comment: I call describe just to quickly check the min/max/std and see that is all zeros. The first 6 categories turn out ok.

Comment: Maybe you have a mixture of integers and strings. Try `input['pattern'].astype(str).str.get_dummies()`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a discussion in the comments, it was deduced that your column contained a mixture of strings and integers.

For example,

```
s = pd.Series(['0', 0, '0', '6', 6, '6', '3', '3'])
s

0    0
1    0
2    0
3    6
4    6
5    6
6    3
7    3
dtype: object
```

Now, calling `pd.get_dummies` would result in multiple such columns of the same feature.

```
pd.get_dummies(s)

   0  6  0  3  6
0  0  0  1  0  0
1  1  0  0  0  0
2  0  0  1  0  0
3  0  0  0  0  1
4  0  1  0  0  0
5  0  0  0  0  1
6  0  0  0  1  0
7  0  0  0  1  0
```

The fix is to ensure that all elements are of the same type. I'd recommend, for this case, converting to `str`.

```
s.astype(str).str.get_dummies()


   0  3  6
0  1  0  0
1  1  0  0
2  1  0  0
3  0  0  1
4  0  0  1
5  0  0  1
6  0  1  0
7  0  1  0
```